# Draw arrows on matplotlib figure directly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I created a plot containing multiple subplots on a grid. The plots differ in two parameters, so I would like it to look like they ordered in a coordinate system.

I managed to plot lines using matplotlib.lines.Line2D() next to the subplots  directly on the figure. 
But I would prefer to have an arrow instead of a line to make it more clear.
(I can add the specific parameter values  using fig.text().)

[I'd like the blue lines to be arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDl8F.png)

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product 

fig = plt.figure()
plotGrid = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

x = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
y = [j* np.sin(x + i)  for i,j in product(range(2), range(1,3))]

for i in range(4):
    ax = plt.Subplot(fig, plotGrid[i])

    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)

    ax.plot(x,y[i], color = 'r')
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

all_axes = fig.get_axes()


#I would like these lines to be arrows  
blcorPosn = 0.08 #bottom corner position
l1 = mpl.lines.Line2D([blcorPosn,blcorPosn], [1, blcorPosn],
                      transform=fig.transFigure, fig)

l2 = mpl.lines.Line2D([blcorPosn, 1], [blcorPosn, blcorPosn],
                      transform=fig.transFigure, fig)

fig.lines.extend([l1, l2])
```

I'm not sure if this is the way to go. But I spend like a day on this by now and the only way I see so far to draw arrows is drawing them directly on an axes but thats not an option for me as far as I can see.

Also this is my first post here so advice on how to ask questions is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html

Comment: Another thing that maybe, just maybe will help you:

http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#annotating-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the Line2D along each axis with a slightly modified call to `FancyArrow` patch. The main difference is that that origin and destination `x,y` coords are replaced with origin `x,y` and a `x,y` distance to draw. The values are also passed as parameters directly, not as lists:

```
l1 = mpl.patches.FancyArrow(blcorPosn, blcorPosn, 1, 0,
                            transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)

l2 = mpl.patches.FancyArrow(blcorPosn, blcorPosn, 0, 1,
                            transform=fig.transFigure, figure=fig)
```

The `FancyArrow` patch accepts a few other parameters to allow you to customise the appearance of the arrow including `width` (for line width), `head_width` and `head_length`.

[image: Figure with axis arrows]